# Who wrote about an energy free space elevator?

Tags: story-identification, robert-a-heinlein

I seem to recall reading of a design by Robert Heinlein (but maybe *Sheffield, Clarke or another scientific writer*), where the energy cost of a space elevator was virtually nil, as descending loads were used to recoup the energy cost of the lift.

Looking for the story,author and if possible the quote where it is described.

Comment: The only Heinlein on [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_elevators_in_fiction) is *Friday*.

Comment: You probably mean [Robert Forward](http://www.frc.ri.cmu.edu/~hpm/project.archive/1976.skyhook/1982.articles/elevate.800322).

Comment: @Micah Edited question; I don't have a copy of Friday handy, but I don't think that was it.  I have surfed around a bit and not find a good list of attributes of each authors elevators.

Comment: @KyleJones in my memory it was described in SciFi story or book.

Comment: I doubt it's in *Friday*, simply because I read that book recently and don't recall Heinlein making much of an issue about the energy-cost of the space elevator in that book. For an engineer, Heinlein often avoided actually going into much detail about the technology in his books. I tend to think Micah is correct. Clarke does go into a lot of detail about his technology, and while I also don't recall the exact passage you mention, I do recall a discussion of the energy-cost of *The Fountain of Paradise*'s space elevator.

Comment: I worked on an answer which is correct, but was deleted as off topic. This was weakly true as I suggested some early authors, but could not be certain or give a quote. But the accepted answer remained 6 weeks undeleted though it did not give a quote. I do now have an answer, with a quote, though it is not a story but a technical analysis of the space elevator, which predates Sheffield, Clarke and Heinlein. It is unclear whether you want the inventor of the idea, or the first use in SF. Adequacy of my answer hinges on that. BTW, the elevator can be net energy producer., but it is a minor point.

Comment: @babou I was looking for the work 'The Fountains of Paradise' There is a quote in the answer, which I added after reading the suggestion.  The scope of this site is Science Fiction so adding or asking for an answer specific to science fact is out of scope.  But would be in scope at http://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you were just looking for 'The Fountains of Paradise', I think
you did not do your homework before asking, since the answer is easy
from Google. I tried *Robert Heinlein Sheffield Clarke space elevator*
and got all the information in the first answer. I also tried *energy
free space elevator* and got an SE answer with a reference to Clarke,
thus indirectly pointing to 'The Fountains of Paradise'. Furthermore,
scientific questions are not off topic, when used in SF. So I assumed
you wanted to know who had first written on energy free elevator, which is actually a very minor issue. Not Clarke

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to find a book about an extraordinary elevator](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/152438/trying-to-find-a-book-about-an-extraordinary-elevator)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you think it might have been Clarke, I would try *The Fountains of Paradise*. I don't remember the specific passage you're talking about, but it predates (and in fact probably caused) the era of science fiction in which space elevators are a common trope, so as I recall it spends more time describing them than most.

**Edit**

Chapter 10 "The Ultimate Bridge"

Quote delivered by the hologram of Vannevar Morgan, Chief Engineer of Terran Construction's Land Division.

> "Capsules for passengers, freight, fuel would ride up and down the tubes, at several thousand kilometers an hour.  Fusion power stations at intervals would provide all the energy needed: since ninety percent of it would be recovered, the net cost per passenger would be only a few dollars.  As the capsules fall earthward again, their motors will act as magnetic brakes, generating electricity. Unlike re-entering spacecraft, they won't waste all their energy heating up the atmosphere and making sonic booms, it will be pumped back into the system.  You could say that the down trains will power the up ones.  So even at the most conservative estimate, the Space Elevator will be a hundred times more efficient than any rocket."

Comment: Charles Sheffield's _The Web Between the Worlds_ came out at about the same time as _The Fountains of Paradise_, so is also worth a look.

Comment: Could not find a "DRM free" copy to buy. I finally figured out how down load as a library loan (it was much easier then I though). Reading now;and here it is, just as I remembered.

Answer (score 13):

As Mike Scott mentions, Sheffields book The Web Between the Worlds fits the bill. Here is the relevant passages, as gleaned from amazon's "look inside" feature:

*..if we send a mass all the way to the end of the beanstalk, far beyond geostationary orbit, the we will also have a free launch system. A mass released from 100,000 kilometers out can be thrown to any part of the solar system. The energy for this is, incidentally, free. It is provided by the rotational energy of the Earth itself* 
[...]
*since any energy used in the drive train to take mass up the beanstalk can be recovered by making the same mass do work as it comes down, a remarkably efficient system is possible. And by using the beanstalk as a slingshot, we have the energy-free launch system for payloads going to destinations anywhere in the solar system*

But note that this is from the book's second appendix, "space elevators in fact and fiction" where the author goes into technical detail. I'm not sure if it's elaborated on in-story or if the appendix was present in the first edition. In any case, and with apologies to Heinlein, there is no such thing as a free launch.

Comment: +10 "In any case, and with apologies to Heinlein, there is no such thing as free launch." :)