# Trying to find a book about an extraordinary elevator

Tags: story-identification, planets

I don't know when I read this, probably a long time since I can't remember most of the plot scenes.

**Plot details I can remember:**

- There's an engineer who, I think, wants to create an elevator. I
  don't know if it's an invention or whatsoever but it's a powerful one.
- I can't remember where the elevator will go but I'm confident
  it'll be a planet - that's why it is powerful.
- There's a part where he plans to construct it in a mountain. I think
  that's where tries to build it but a monk tries to sabotage it.
- The antagonist is a monk.

**Note**: Sorry if I only gave little information. That's all I can remember from that story. Maybe some of you already read it and forgot it too, you can edit this question to add more information. I googled all info I can remember but it doesn't match the same book I'm trying to find.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That is most likely Arthur C. Clarke's *[The Fountains of Paradise](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1903)*.

The engineer is Dr Vannevar Morgan, who wants to construct a space elevator, an elevator that stretches out into space. This elevator is made possible through the use of "hyperfilament",  a monomolecular wire.

The mountain is on Taprobane, or Sri Lanka. The mountain is home to a monastery, the monks unwilling to move. But in an attempt by an ex-monk to sabotage an experiment, an ancient prophesy is unwittingly fulfilled, causing the monks to leave.

A second story in the background, is the arrival of an alien probe.

Comment: If it is, there's a question with the same answer: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/39660/70236

Comment: @SQB yes this is it! I remember it now. I also searched up the book's cover and I still remember the design of a mountain and other objects.

Comment: @Gallifreyan yes, I think so. Sorry for the duplicate. I did a research in this site but I can't find a topic pertaining to this book.

Comment: @BookStriker duplicates are good - now it'll be easier for others to find this book.

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe the 2005 book [Mercury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_(novel)) by Ben Bova?

> "Mance was the chief visionary and engineer behind the skytower, a
>   super space elevator which ran from Ecuador all the way into low Earth
>   orbit. When religious fundamentalists and agents of the scheming
>   Yamagata Corporation sabotage the skytower, however, millions are
>   killed; Mance is faced with his own guilt for the tragedy and sees
>   himself as ostensibly responsible"

Comment: Could you [explain](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9445/20774) why the novel would be a match?

Comment: It's been ten years since I read it but it meets the criteria of your question.

Comment: ... As I was saying, it's been a while.  I can't really go back and read it at the moment.  I'd love to, but I have insane amounts of pressure right now at work and just, can't, do it.  I'm an ER doc and as much as I love Obamacare, it's given me 18x more business than I can handle.  You're going to have to read it yourself.  It's not a waste of time.  Bova has stuff that really irritates me but he is also a really good writer and story teller.  The thing is that the stuff about the space elevator is all in the first 7% of the book.  It becomes a little blah after that.  IMHO. Clarke reference

Comment: No doubt Clarke PWNS the space elevator stuff (ok, we are not even talking about Charlie and the Great Glass Elevator, right?).  But hey.