# In which Arthur C Clarke short story did an alien ship monitor earth, and leave, answering only basic earthling questions

Tags: story-identification

Arthur C Clarke alien ship monitoring earth

Comment: Welcome to Sci-Fi. Is there anything else you can tell us about the story, such as approximately where or when you read it?

Comment: This question is very (very) terse. You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: It sounds like "Encounter in the Dawn", which has aliens visit earth in pre-history.

Comment: could be Rendevous with Rama, without more details

Comment: Thank you all.....I think GordonD may have it.

Comment: I have looked everywhere, and i have a decent collection to investigate, and this would explain my inability to locate it. Will get back to you on this GD

Comment: I thank you GordonD.....you were spot on. Starglider makes its appearance in Part ll, and  in Ch 16, Conversations with Starglider, i found what i have been looking for. FOP was one of my earlier ACC reads, and I have read many since, but that encounter remains one of my very favorite passages. Thank you!!

Comment: I recognize that you may have an answer you that you want to accept. Nonetheless, can you add the additional details elicited into your question? As it is, this is not much use for future querents.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Who wrote about an energy free space elevator?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39639/who-wrote-about-an-energy-free-space-elevator)

Comment: see OP confirmation comment above

Answer (score 4):

Could it be Starglider in [*The Fountains of Paradise*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fountains_of_Paradise)? That was a novel, not a short story, but the Starglider incident was only a small part, seen in flashback. It was an alien probe which traded information, but nothing on advanced technology, before departing the Solar System.